# paypal add to cart button // multilanguage support

Tags: paypal

Good day everyone,

need to code the following fucntionality on my multilanguage site.
If my customer javascript selects to view the site in e.g. german, the "add to cart" button must change to german and when pressed, open a german version of the cart.

I am having a hard time in finding info on how to javascript the flow described above. Anyone knows any link i could dig in?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things you would need to do to make this work. When you change the language you need to set a few things in the button:

You need to update the *lc* value to that of the country you are selecting eg:

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US" />
```

to

```
<input type="hidden" name="lc" value="DE" />
```

and you would also want to update the button image:

```
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_cart_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
```

to

```
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/de_DE/i/btn/btn_cart_SM.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!" />
```

Which will update the button image.

You can find the country codes and their "locale" at https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECButtonIntegration/

I have created a simple example of this in action at: http://jsfiddle.net/F5VM2/14/